# it's possible to make listview in expand and fill parent without overflow?

Tags: flutter, listview

it's possible to make listview in expand and fill the container without overflow the container, and shrink when listview is short of content without declare manual min or max height?

Code

```
Flexible(
  fit: FlexFit.loose,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kBoxRadius),
        boxShadow: [kBoxShadow]),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        DText(
          "Aug 2021",
          size: 12,
          weight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Row(
          children: dates,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15),
        Container(
          height: 1,
          color: Color(0xFFE7E7E7),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints:
              BoxConstraints(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 600),
          child: ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return DText("Asd");
            },
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) {
              return SizedBox(height: 10);
            },
            itemCount: 20,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

[Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHVDp.png)

[when the content is big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj7aJ.png)

because i set manually max height.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using `shrinkWrap: true`. The code will be something like below,

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(),
       body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(title: Text('Apple')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Orange')),
              ListTile(title: Text('Banana')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```